# I have a problem with my Airlock

Tags: airlock

The lid on my airlock has no holes in the top! Do I still make sure the lid is firmly all the way down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some airlocks that have plastic lines such that when you put the top on there are small openings on the side of the lock to let CO2 escape.  Perhaps yours is like that.

It is possible to just leave the top off.  Just make sure that all the liquid does not evaporate.